# How to move focus from textbox to textbox int contentcontrol in wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, focus, contentcontrol

I want to move focus from Title Textbox to Textbox in ContentControl in WPF.
But any command doesn't work.
How can I move focus?

```
    <TextBox
        Grid.Row="0"
        MinWidth="200"
        Name="Title"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        mahApps:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True"
        mahApps:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Task Title"
        Text="{Binding Title, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,5,0,5"
        Background="White">
        <ContentControl
            MinHeight="55"
            Margin="5"
            Content="{Binding CreateTaskControl}" />
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `Focusable="True"` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"`
And of course if `TabIndex` you did not use it.

this code `Focusable="True"` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"` Useful for places that do not accept the TabIndex element, such as TextBlock